# Ionic Capacitor 3 Google login error {"message : Something went wrong"}

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, google-signin

Hi Can any One Please help me to resolve this i tried all, same error follows only for android.

**Error : message: "Something went wrong"**

Cap 3 Plugin I have used

```
npm i --save @codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth
```

Steps i Followed

after generate firebase project and stored the google-services.json in android root folder

capacitor.config.json

```
"GoogleAuth": {
          "scopes": ["profile", "email"],
          "serverClientId": "290196494248-471hnb4qt4pq7dnj56tgsil2sa358111.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "forceCodeForRefreshToken" : true
        }
```

Strings.xml

```
<string name="server_client_id">290196494248-471hnb4qt4pq7dnj56tgsil2sa358111.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
```

login function

```
 GoogleAuth.signIn();
```

**After I selected the google account on retriving data it show's this error, it works fine in IOS**

Answer (score -1):

I see the same error on simulators. It works fine on a real device.
Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the tour to see [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). I think your answer should be a comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the tour to see [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). I think your answer should be a comment.

Comment: it is not working here even on production a mobile device.

Comment: It used to work on my Android device, not anymore. Did you find a solution ?